# Glassfish server and Polymer

Tags: javascript, jsp, glassfish, polymer, glassfish-4.1

I would like to create a login page using Polymer. The login page is now created in JSP file and is associated with the Glassfish server. 
How I can import now my own polymer-element or simple paper-button? Is this possible? Simple example what I have tried:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="<bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <paper-button>Login</paper-button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**this is error:**
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (15:31:33:007 | error, javascript)
  at http://localhost:8080/WebApplicationTEST/%3Cbower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js:3

Answer (score 0):

The value of your `src` attribute in the `script` tag should not start with an `<`, removing it should do the trick.

Comment: I removed that and I have the same error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (21:56:22:889 | error, javascript)
  at web/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js:3

Comment: On http://webcomponents.org/, you can download the un-minified version of the webcomponents polyfill (webcomponents.js). If you import this instead of the minified version, maybe the error could be narrowed down.

Comment: nothing... I think that this problem comes because glassfish server does not know how to interpret polymer-element. When I use 
`<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>` 
than works. If I use aut-method FORM where I would specify my own login page, than I have this problem.

P.S: for dowloading the elements of polymer I use bower